# Generar multiples dataframes y luego concatenarlos en un big-dataframe en python

Tags: dataframe, diccionarios, concat

Presento el siguiente problema en mi código.
Estoy desarrollando un código en donde quiero generar varios DataFrames y luego concatenarlos (realizar append). He leído que se pueden utilizar diccionarios, pero no encuentro la manera en como aplicarlos.

Pudieran apoyarme con una sugerencia de código que mejore el que tengo.

Adjunto el código:

```py
ENTREGAS_G1=['19052022','27052022',
             '02062022','06062022','13062022','20062022','27062022',
             '05072022','11072022','20072022','26072022',
             '01082022']

for i in range(len(ENTREGAS_G1)):
    print('INFORMACION_'+ENTREGAS_G1[i])
    
    lista_date = folder_listas+'/SOLICITUD_INFORMACION_'+ENTREGAS_G1[i]
    
    esta = DBF(os.path.join(lista_date,'SOLICITUD_INFORMACION_'+ENTREGAS_G1[i]+'_ESTABLECIMIENTOS.DBF'))
    DF_ESTA=pd.DataFrame(iter(esta))
    prec = DBF(os.path.join(lista_date,'SOLICITUD_INFORMACION_'+ENTREGAS_G1[i]+'_PRECIOS.DBF'))
    DF_PREC=pd.DataFrame(iter(prec))
    prod = DBF(os.path.join(lista_date,'SOLICITUD_INFORMACION_'+ENTREGAS_G1[i]+'_PRODUCTOS.DBF'))
    DF_PROD=pd.DataFrame(iter(prod))
    
    MERGE1 = pd.merge(DF_PREC, DF_PROD, on=['CVE_PRODUC','CVE_MARCA'])
    MERGE2 = pd.merge(DF_ESTA, MERGE1, on='FOLIO')
    
    PROFECO['i'] = MERGE2.assign(identrega=ENTREGAS_G1[i])
    
    print('Done:','PROFECO_'+ENTREGAS_G1[i])

ENTREGAS = ENTREGAS_G1+ENTREGAS_G2+ENTREGAS_G3
print(ENTREGAS)
string = 'PROFECO_'
LIST = [string + x for x in ENTREGAS]
print(LIST)

PROFECO_ACUM230220 = pd.concat([LIST])
```

Según yo, mi error esta en:

```py
    PROFECO['i'] = MERGE2.assign(identrega=ENTREGAS_G1[i])
```

E igual no sé si la parte de concatenar es correcta.

Saludos, agradecería mucho su apoyo.

Alexis Rodas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La clave del diccionario, en la línea que señalas, sería siempre la cadena `"i"`, por lo que en cada iteración estarías escribiendo siempre en la misma posición del diccionario, "machacando" lo que habías metido ahí en iteraciones previas.

Entiendo que querías poner en cambio `PROFECO[i]`, pues de ese modo en lugar de la cadena "i" estás usando el *valor* de la variable `i`. Faltaría crear un diccionario vacío antes de entrar al bucle, con `PROFECO = {}`.

No obstante, `i` en este caso es una variable de tipo entero que va tomando los valores 0, 1, 2, ... por lo que parece que mejor usarías aquí una lista en lugar de un diccionario. El diccionario podría tener sentido si quisieras después acceder a sus elementos por una clave de tipo texto. Por ejemplo, que la clave fuese '19052022', o '27052022', etc. Pero si la clave van a ser enteros consecutivos comenzando en 0, veo más sentido a usar una lista.

Especialmente si al final lo vas a concatenar todo con `pd.concat()` ya que en ese caso pasar el diccionario a esa función no sería correcto, pues `pd.concat()` iteraría por las claves del diccionario en vez de por sus valores (que son los dataframes que quieres concatenar).

En definitiva, modificaría tu código para:

1. Crear una lista inicial vacía `PROFECO = []`
2. En cada iteración del bucle añadir (mediante append) un nuevo dataframe a esa lista.
3. Pasar esa lista a `pd.concat()` al terminar el bucle

Y ya de paso, propongo otras mejoras, para hacerlo más pythónico y más legible:

1. En vez de iterar por los índices `i`, iterar directamente por las cadenas que hay dentro de `ENTREGAS_G1`. Basta poner por ejemplo `for num in ENTREGAS_G1:`. Y de ese modo ya no necesitas escribir `ENTREGAS_G1[i]` tantas veces, basta poner `num` en su lugar.
2. Usar f-strings en vez de concatenaciones, para crear los nombres de archivos o para los print.

Con estos cambios tu código queda así:

```
ENTREGAS_G1=['19052022','27052022',
             '02062022','06062022','13062022','20062022','27062022',
             '05072022','11072022','20072022','26072022',
             '01082022']

PROFECO = []

for num in ENTREGAS_G1:
    print(f'INFORMACION_{num}')

    lista_date = f"{folder_listas}/SOLICITUD_INFORMACION_{num}"
    esta = DBF(os.path.join(lista_date, f'SOLICITUD_INFORMACION_{num}_ESTABLECIMIENTOS.DBF'))
    DF_ESTA=pd.DataFrame(iter(esta))
    prec = DBF(os.path.join(lista_date, f'SOLICITUD_INFORMACION_{num}_PRECIOS.DBF'))
    DF_PREC=pd.DataFrame(iter(prec))
    prod = DBF(os.path.join(lista_date, f'SOLICITUD_INFORMACION_{num}_PRODUCTOS.DBF'))
    DF_PROD=pd.DataFrame(iter(prod))

    MERGE1 = pd.merge(DF_PREC, DF_PROD, on=['CVE_PRODUC','CVE_MARCA'])
    MERGE2 = pd.merge(DF_ESTA, MERGE1, on='FOLIO')

    PROFECO.append(MERGE2.assign(identrega=num))
    print(f'Done: PROFECO_{num}')

# Estas líneas no sé qué hacían, pues no estaban definidas ENTREGAS_G2 y ENTREGAS_G3
# asi que lo comento
# ENTREGAS = ENTREGAS_G1+ENTREGAS_G2+ENTREGAS_G3
# print(ENTREGAS)
# string = 'PROFECO_'
# LIST = [string + x for x in ENTREGAS]
# print(LIST)

PROFECO_ACUM230220 = pd.concat(PROFECO)
```